# Align different part of multiple li in a single ul

Tags: alignment, html-lists

What i have:

```
<ul class="store-opening-hours">
    <li class="day-1"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Maandag: 09:00 - 18:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-2"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Dinsdag: 09:00 - 18:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-3"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Woensdag: 09:00 - 18:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-4"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Donderdag: 09:00 - 21:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-5"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Vrijdag: 09:00 - 18:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-6"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Zaterdag: 09:00 - 17:00</span></li>
    <li class="day-0"><span style="color: #808080; font-family: futura_lt;">Zondag: Gesloten</span></li>
</ul>
```

Result:

```
Maandag: 09:00 – 18:00
Dinsdag: 09:00 – 18:00
Woensdag: 09:00 – 18:00
Donderdag: 09:00 – 21:00
Vrijdag: 09:00 – 18:00
Zaterdag: 09:00 – 17:00
Zondag: Gesloten
```

I would like to have the days aligned to the left as they are now, but the times (everything after : ) to the right... How? I cant seem to get it right...